# is it possible to change zindex of vector layer on hover on vector layer in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have 2 vector layers .to which I set initially that way that inside_buffer is on top. like this

> this.app.inside_vector.setZIndex(80);

So I want now when user hover over this inside vector layer my

> this.app.vector.setZIndex(76);

should have more zindex then inside vector ?  is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the problem. Of course you can change z-index of layers, independently from a limit of initial value. Take a look for example in [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-z-index.html).

Comment: On hover of move I want to change . in openlayer2 preferably